# Event handling problems

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, nested-function

Good day.
How do I pass a parameter to an event handler? Consider this code:

```
const displayDetails = (details) => {button.addEventListener('click', showDetails)};
```

How do I pass `details` as an argument to the event handler `showDetails` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap "showDetails" with another function like this:

```
const displayDetails = (details) => {button.addEventListener('click', () => showDetails(details))};
```